# C++ STL: Finding string in vector of string using std::find doesn't work

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, stl

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> vs;
    vs.push_back("i");
    vs.push_back("like");
    vs.push_back("apples");
    vs.push_back("but");
    vs.push_back("am");
    vs.push_back("allergic");
    vs.push_back("to");
    vs.push_back("apples");

    string sbut("but");

    string s = find(vs.begin(), vs.end(), sbut);
    s = find(vs.begin(), vs.end(), "but");

    return 1;
}
```

this is the test code I have.
I have a scenario where I store strings in a vector and must check whether a string exists in this vector.

I get the following error message but I can't understand, the two cases of find returns different types of errors:

```
stringfind.cpp:20:47: error: conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ requested
     string s = find(vs.begin(), vs.end(), sbut);

stringfind.cpp:21:7: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >’)
     s = find(vs.begin(), vs.end(), "but");
```

from compiling with -std=c++11 option

Could anybody enlighten me with what is going on and how I can achieve the scenario?

edit: sorry I meant I do the checking using

```
if(vs.end()!=find(vs.begin(),vs.end(), "but")
```

wrote the test program too quickly

Comment: Did you even read the documentation for [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: Since when does `std::find` return a string? And why are you trying to store the result in a string again, anyway? You already have it: it's `sbut`. -1 for not even pretending to do the slightest bit of research.

Answer (score 4):

`find` returns an iterator, not a string. You need to check that the iterator is valid to see if the string was found.

```
vector<string>::iterator it = find(vs.begin(), vs.end(), sbut);
if (it != vs.end()) {
    // string found!
}
```

Comment: You don't even need to do this. If the search succeeded, then you already have your string: it's `sbut`.

Comment: For a more complete answer, you may want to explain why there are two different error messages for the two calls.